# Source Code of the existing object in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a function in my database named f_Get_Employee_Details. I want to generate script for the existing function. How to do it in Oracle ?

I mostly work on SQL Server and Its like buying Candy from shop in SQL Server.

Comment: Generate gcript for an existing function? Elaborate a little. You want to get source code of that function?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov : Thats right. I want to get Source Code. As I told I use SQL Server mostly and it uses word "Script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use the `DBMS_METADATA` builtin package. (I've assumed here that you're logged in as the owner of the function - if not, you just need to specify the correct schema name)

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(
    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL
      (object_type     => 'FUNCTION'
      ,name            => 'f_Get_Employee_Details'
      ,schema          => USER
      )
    );
END;
```

Comment: Thanx... This solution seems more generic than using user_Source because can get source code for Tables as well.

Comment: Yep, this is how most of the GUI tools do it. `user_source` and its cousins are more useful if you want to do searches across your source code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get source code of a stored procedure query **user_source** or **all_source** or **dba_source** static  views